# Use neo4j in android device

Tags: android, neo4j

I am trying to create a database in my android device with NEO4J. But the application crashes.

```
 String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 GraphDatabaseService graphDB=new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(extStorageDirectory);
```

I have added permissions for writing to external storage.

What may be the reason? Is it at all possible to create a neo4j database in Android device?

Comment: 1. How do you embed Neo4j?
2. What is the error you get after your app crashes?

Comment: There are some upcoming news about Neo4j on Android, stay tuned.

Answer (score 5):

The news to which Michael alluded has just come out: Neo4j Mobile for Android v0.1. It's still in incubation, and we'd love your feedback.

More details here: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/new-incubator-project-neo4j-mobile-for.html