# What Spatial Databases are there for mobile devices?

Tags: database, mobile, spatial

I am looking for a lightweight Spatial database that could be used locally on a mobile device to store spatial objects; point, line, polygon.

What are the different databases that are capable of storing spatial objects that could be used on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

The following are spatial database solutions for mobile:

1. [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) (a geospatial extension of SQLite). For that, there is a [SpatiaLite on Android tutorial](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial), and a [blog post on compiling SpatiaLite for iOS](https://aaronparecki.com/2015/05/21/11/).
2. [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/), a graph database with a [geospatial extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial). See the blog posts on [Neo4j Mobile for Android](http://neo4j.com/blog/new-incubator-project-neo4j-mobile-for-android-v0-1/) and [Geospatial Indexing](http://neo4j.com/blog/geospatial-indexing-us-congress-neo4j/).
3. [SpatialDBKit](https://github.com/andreacremaschi/SpatialDBKit), "An Objective-C lightweight spatial RDBMS (based on SQLite/SpatiaLite)".

Related questions:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/what-native-spatially-enabled-sdk-options-are-there-to-deploy-gis-data-on-ios-an
- [Spatialite and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463305/spatialite-and-ios)
- [how to compile spatialite for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793970/how-to-compile-spatialite-for-ios)
- [Use neo4j in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458188/use-neo4j-in-android-device)